# I can't figure out the problem in this code about python, need help

Tags: python, xhtml

I'm going to create a game, user put in the name and bet number and my program is gonna show the bet number is greater than the sum of 5 random dice and show each picture of them. I know there is something wrong but I dont know where

```
import cgi
import random

formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
playerName = formData["name"].value
playerGuess = int(formData["guess"].value)
theLength = 5
index =1
print "Content-type: text/html"


print "<p>Thanks for playing, " + playerName + ",</p>"
for die in range(theLength):
    die%i = random.randint(1,6)%index
    if int(die) == 1:
        print "<img src = "Images/dice-1.gif" alt="1" width="107" height="107" />"
    elif int(die) == 2:
        print "<img src = "Images/dice-2.gif" alt="2" width="107" height="107" />"
    elif int(die) == 3:
        print "<img src = "Images/dice-3.gif" alt="3" width="107" height="107" />"
    elif int(die) == 4:
        print "<img src = "Images/dice-4.gif" alt="4" width="107" height="107" />"
    elif int(die) == 5:
        print "<img src = "Images/dice-5.gif" alt="5" width="107" height="107" />"
    elif int(die) == 6:
        print "<img src = "Images/dice-6.gif" alt="6" width="107" height="107" />"
    index = index + 1
    total = die%i + die%i

print "<p>You bet the total would be at least " + playerGuess + ". The total rolled was " + sum + ".</p>"

if int(guessNumber) >= total:
    print "<p>You won!</p>"
else:
    print """<p>Sorry, you lose!</p>
```

Comment: I bet there is something wrong... but what?  What are you expecting?  What are you actually getting?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Would you mind telling us what is wrong with the behaviour of the program. Tell us the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour. Please spend more time thinking about how to ask your question before you fall back on the crutch of Stack Overflow. You'll become a better programmer if you do.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
die%i = random.randint(1,6)%index
```

Is not valid python syntax. It's cousin a few lines below:

```
total = die%i + die%i
```

Will not give you the results you're expecting; the `%`'s will be treated as mod operators.  That loop should be something more like:

```
for die in range(theLength):
    val = random.randint(1,6)
    print '<img src = "Images/dice-%i.gif" alt="%i" width="107" height="107" />' % (val, val)
```

Even with those changes, it will still exception because `sum` is an undefined variable when you use it to print the total.   You'll need to keep track of it in your "roll loop."

```
sum = 0
for die in range(theLength):
    val = random.randint(1,6)
    print "<img src = 'Images/dice-%i.gif" alt="%i" width="107" height="107" />' % (val, val)
    total = total + val
```

Comment: `total = die%i + die%i` is perfectly valid python syntax.

Comment: @cdhowie, ha! thanks.  I'll update the post to more accurately reflect the behavior.

Comment: Don't use builtins as variable named (sum).

Comment: @agf, ack! between the mod operators and *that*, perhaps I should be asking the questions. Will update to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending correct HTTP answers; after the final header, a newline is supposed to come, so you're looking for:

```
print("Content-Type: text/plain")
print("")
```

Also, the first `%i` in

```
die%i = random.randint(1,6)%index
```

is a syntax error; the left side has to be a reference to a variable.

And instead of `total = die%i + die%i`, you probably wanted `total += die%index` and `total = 0` at the very top.

By the way, you can greatly simplify the big `if .. elif` block by writing

```
print "<img src = "Images/dice-%s.gif" alt="1" width="107" height="107" />" % die
```

Answer (score 0):

The line is invalid because you want to assign to a result of an operation.

```
die%i = random.randint(1,6)%index
```

For example if say die is 5 and i is 1 then it would result that:

```
0 = random.randint(1,6)%index
```

Which doesn't make any sense.